# Convert float price to integer price without commas

Tags: python, formatting, floating-point

My payment gateway wants the prices this way: "1050" instead of 10.50.
So I created this function:

https://repl.it/HgHI/3

```
def price_format_gateway(price):
    price = "{0:.2f}".format(price)
    price = price.split(".")
    try:
      if len(price[1]) > 2:
        decimals = str(price[1][0:2])
      else:
        decimals = price[1]
    except IndexError:
      pass

    return str(price[0]) + str(decimals)


price_format_gateway(10) # Expected -> 1000
price_format_gateway(10.1) # Expected -> 1010
price_format_gateway(10.15765) # Expected -> 1016
```

Is there another way more elegant, or cleaner? I just want to improve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to round a number to a specific number of digits, instead use `round`. Here you can use `round(price, 2)`. The string format performs this too, so, if you perform the string format to force two decimal places, you can get the number rounded to two decimals separated by a period. I.e `10.16`. You then just want to remove the period, and so you can just use `'10.00'.replace('.', '')`, and so you can drastically simplify this to:

```
def price_format_gateway(price):
    return '{:.2f}'.format(price).replace('.', '')
```

Answer (score 6):

For me at least, it would be more natural to think of the operation as a multiplication by 100:

```
def price_format_gateway(price):
    return '{:.0f}'.format(100 * price)
```